# Deep nested eloquent aggregates with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have a semi-ecommerce site with a few models: User, Product, Cart, and Detail.

`Cart` is simply a pivot table whereas `Detail` contains the quantity and order-specific details.

I've hit a wall in attempting to calculate the total value of a cart. How do I get the aggregate for the products belonging to a specific cart? I've tried doing several variations of the following to no avail:

```
$sum = $cart->details->products->sum('price');
```

I invariably get a `Call to undefined method` exception.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would do something like Cart::with('details.products')->sum('price') but I'm not sure about what sum is going to do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$cart->details->products()->sum('price');` $cart->details->products is a collection, while $cart->details->products() is a querybuilder object.

Comment: Must have forgotten to mark this before. This wasn't quite the exact solution I needed but it turned me onto the querybuilder vs. collection idea. Thanks for the tip!